# Healing Tooth Decay via Electrically Accelerated and Enhanced Remineralisation?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, dentistry

According to [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2014/jun/16/fillings-dentists-tooth-decay-treatment) scientists from the UK have developed a tool to repair cavities without filling or injections.

> The new treatment, called Electrically Accelerated and Enhanced
>   Remineralisation (EAER), accelerates the natural movement of calcium
>   and phosphate minerals into the damaged tooth.
>
> A two-step process first prepares the damaged area of enamel, then
>   uses a tiny electric current to push minerals into the repair site.

I found this claim very interesting. I went to the manufacturer's website to learn more about how this works and saw this:

> Our invention accelerates the mineral uptake but also drives the
>   mineral right to the deepest part of the subsurface lesion and
>   rebuilds substantially all of the damage.  For this reason we called
>   it Electrically Assisted Enhanced Remineralization (EAER). This uses a
>   tiny electrical current of a few micro Amps (a millionth of an Amp)
>   that is too small to cause any physical sensation in the patient, to
>   help accelerate mineral ions deep into the tooth enamel and providing
>   a complete rebuild of the caries affected tissue rather than just a
>   remineralization limited to just the enamel surface.

Based on my limited research it seems like this tech uses ultrasound-driven **iontophoresis** to transport minerals into the tooth to reverse tooth decay.

Is there any evidence that such an intervention might reverse tooth decay? The only other use of iontophoresis I found was to treat hyperhidrosis so there's limited information about this idea.